# How to add "swab" to text string when "dry0" occurs in R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have a column with swab IDs. The normal ID nomenclature is "dryswab00001". However there are some samples as "dry00135". How would I str_detect those IDs and insert "swab" before the leading zero/number?

#### Data

```
data <- structure(list(swab_id = c("dryswab00001", "dry00002")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_detect` and `str_replace` in stringr to do this:

```
install.packages("stringr")
library("stringr")

# Use str_detect to identify IDs that need modification
update <- str_detect(data$swab_id, "^dry\\d+")

# Modify the IDs
data$swab_id[update] <- str_replace(data$swab_id[update], "^dry", "dryswab")
```

Final dataframe:
swab_id 
1 dryswab00001 
2 dryswab00002

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` with capture group

```
sub("(^dry)(\\d+.*)", "\\1swab\\2", data$swab_id)
[1] "dryswab00001" "dryswab00002"
```